# Ubuntu 14.04 OpenCl Intel SDK error: "Error while loading shared libraries"

Tags: installation, opencl, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install OpenCl with an Intel GPU under Ubuntu 14.04.

I followed this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/rmcgibbo/6314452, but
no matter what I do I get this error:

> Error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Step 5 in the tutorial instructed you to create a symlink (`/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so`) that points to Intel's version of `libOpenCL.so`, which in turn will be a symlink to a `libOpenCL.so.1`. When you linked your application against `/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so`, the symlinks were resolved and the `.1` version of the library was used. When you run the application, it then tries to find a `libOpenCL.so.1` on the dynamic library search path, which it cannot.

To fix this, you can just remove the symlink the tutorial asked you to create and set-up new symlinks that take this versioning into account. For example:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-3.0.67279/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1  /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1  /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so
```